# How can I set a subdirectory as the root directory in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want set a subfolder as the root folder, what means rewrite every requested URL by appending a directory before their root, like

```
example.com/cat/ -> example.com/public/cat/
example.com/cat/black/ -> example.com/public/cat/black/
example.com/public/cat/ -> example.com/public/public/cat/
```

I've tried

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

But when I requested any of its page, I got Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is correct so far. The internal error comes from an endless rewrite loop.

When you request `example.com/cat`, it will be rewritten to `example.com/public/cat`. But this new URL is fed back into the rewrite module and again, `example.com/public/cat` is rewritten to `example.com/public/public/cat`, which is rewritten to `example.com/public/public/public/cat`, and so on, until some internal counter is exceeded and Apache reports an internal error.

To fix this, you must add a [condition](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), which tells Apache to stop rewriting any further. For this, you can use one of the [variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html#variables), which are set by Apache, when a rewrite occurs.

```
RewriteCond %{REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

This checks, if `REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty (`^$`). When it is empty, do the rewrite. After the rewrite, `REDIRECT_STATUS` will be set and not empty, and as a consequence no further rewrites will be done.

---

If you wouldn't rewrite

```
example.com/public/cat/ -> example.com/public/public/cat/
```

you could also check, if the requested URL doesn't start with `public`, e.g.

```
RewriteRule !^public/ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: That's weird. I thought that if I don't redirect, it'll just send the file from the rewritten path, not restart the whole thing. Checking the redirect status is kinda hacky, so I will go with the second one. There is no flag or something for just rewriting the path of the response? Or maybe with the help of PHP without breaking the semantics of the structure?

Comment: You can see an image of Apache's [Ruleset Processing](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset), where it shows that on "URI changed", the cycle starts again. `RewriteRule` is the directive for rewriting requests. You can also use PHP, and do the same by looking at [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and serving the appropriate content.

Comment: I haven't tried the [`END`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) flag, but maybe this works for your purpose.

Comment: OK then I will direct every request to one PHP file and control everything there, and using .htaccess for making the links SEO friendly.